# Works on WPF. But on VSTO project, throws error: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.2.669, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, vsto, microsoft.data.sqlite

I've created a `.NET Standard 2.0` class library project that works fine when referenced by a `WPF App (.NET Framework 4.8)` project. But when the same library is referenced by a [MS Office VSTO Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) (also using .NET Framework 4.8), I get the following error on the code line shown below:

**Remarks**:

1. I'm using `VS2019`, `Windows20 Pro`, [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli) and following [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli#usage) from same link.
2. Exact same code works fine on `WPF` app.
3. I also tried installing `SQLitePCLRaw.core` package (as mentioned in the error) but still the same error. Although, I think I should not have to install this package since I did not have to do it with `WPF` app.
4. Same copies of `MySQLiteDb.db` file reside in the `bin\Debug` folder of `VSTO` as well as `WPF` folder. So, that should probably not be an issue

**Error**:

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.2.669, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

**Code** [error occurs at line `using (SqliteConnection db = ....)`:

```
string SQLiteDbpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetAppInstalPath, "MySQLiteDb.db");

using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={SQLiteDbpath}"))
{
    db.Open();

    using (SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand())
    {
        ......
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors if you set the target framework version to any lower version?

Answer (score 0):

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.2.669, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

You need to include the missed file (SQLitePCLRaw.core) to the folder with the add-in files.

Comment: As mentioned in `item 3` of my `Remarks` above, I already tried installing it but still the same error. If you look at this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#the-minimum-version-of-your-project-targets-the-fall-creators-update) you will get an idea of what packages get installed on which project (the main project and the .NET Standard project). The only difference between that tutorial and mine is that they are using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` (because their main project is UWP) and I'm using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`