# MS Office Add-in error when inheriting a class from DbContext

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-core, office365, vsto

I’m trying to create a Word [VSTO Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) project in Visual Studio 16.6.1 targeting `.NET Framework 4.8`. I want to use [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/) to access information in a database. However, as soon as I add a class that inherits from `DbContext`, I can no longer build the project. I get an error reporting:

```
The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly. 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddInTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

WordAddinTest is the name of my project.

I can reproduce this using these minimal steps:

1. Create a new Visual Basic project of type Word VSTO Add-in.
2. Set the name to WordAddinTest, and the Framework to Framework .NET Framework 4.8.
3. Using the Nuget Package Manager, install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`.
4. Replace the default code in ThisAddIn.vb with the following:

Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestClass
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
End Class

Public Class TestContext
    'Inherits DbContext
    'NOTE: If the line above is excluded, it will compile (but obviously without EntityFramework support)

    Public Property TestProperty As DbSet(Of TestClass)
End Class
```

This will compile, run and debug without problems.

However, uncommenting the line indicated so that TestContext inherits from DbContext, it no longer compiles, and the Error List displays the following error:

```
The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddInTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'WordAddInTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. WordAddInTest
```

Noting the advice at the end about Fusion Logging, if I set that registry value it adds the following information:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = WordAddInTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/applications/programming/Visual Studio 2019 Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\applications\programming\Visual Studio 2019 Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/applications/programming/Visual Studio 2019 Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/WordAddInTest.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/applications/programming/Visual Studio 2019 Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/WordAddInTest/WordAddInTest.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/applications/programming/Visual Studio 2019 Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/WordAddInTest.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/applications/programming/Visual Studio 2019 Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/WordAddInTest/WordAddInTest.EXE.   WordAddInTest
```

Visual Studio is looking for my Add-in DLL in the MSBuild directory.

Is it just not possible to use Entity Framework in a VSTO Add-in project?
Is there another logical explanation for why it can’t compile?
I haven’t been able to find any other reports of the same problem, and I can’t imagine I’m the first person to try it.

I realize there is more required to actually use the EntityFramework to access a database, but this is a compilation error, so it isn’t even getting that far.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

**UPDATE**:

Following is `.vbproj` (equivalent of .csproj) file in case it can shed some light on identifying/solving the issue:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="16.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <!--
    This section defines project-level properties.

    AssemblyName
      Name of the output assembly.
    Configuration
      Specifies a default value for debug.
    OutputType
      Must be "Library" for VSTO.
    Platform
      Specifies what CPU the output of this project can run on.
    NoStandardLibraries
      Set to "false" for VSTO.
    RootNamespace
      In C#, this specifies the namespace given to new files. In VB, all objects are
      wrapped in this namespace at runtime.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A4902970-1F65-45A0-AED0-5B3398DFE0CD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <NoStandardLibraries>false</NoStandardLibraries>
    <RootNamespace>WordAddinTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WordAddinTest</AssemblyName>
    <LoadBehavior>3</LoadBehavior>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <DefineConstants>VSTO40</DefineConstants>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <BootstrapperComponentsLocation>HomeSite</BootstrapperComponentsLocation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.VSTORuntime.4.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--
      OfficeApplication
        Add-in host application
    -->
    <OfficeApplication>Word</OfficeApplication>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!--
    This section defines properties that are set when the "Debug" configuration is selected.

    DebugSymbols
      If "true", create symbols (.pdb). If "false", do not create symbols.
    DefineConstants
      Constants defined for the preprocessor.
    EnableUnmanagedDebugging
      If "true", starting the debugger will attach both managed and unmanaged debuggers.
    Optimize
      If "true", optimize the build output. If "false", do not optimize.
    OutputPath
      Output path of project relative to the project file.
    WarningLevel
      Warning level for the compiler.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!--
    This section defines properties that are set when the "Release" configuration is selected.

    DebugSymbols
      If "true", create symbols (.pdb). If "false", do not create symbols.
    DefineConstants
      Constants defined for the preprocessor.
    EnableUnmanagedDebugging
      If "true", starting the debugger will attach both managed and unmanaged debuggers.
    Optimize
      If "true", optimize the build output. If "false", do not optimize.
    OutputPath
      Output path of project relative to the project file.
    WarningLevel
      Warning level for the compiler.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!--
    This section specifies references for the project.
  -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Accessibility" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--
    This section defines the user source files that are part of the project.

    A "Compile" element specifies a source file to compile.
    An "EmbeddedResource" element specifies an .resx file for embedded resources.
    A "None" element specifies a file that is not to be passed to the compiler (for instance, 
    a text file or XML file).
    The "AppDesigner" element specifies the directory where the application properties files
    can be found.
  -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Model.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="WordAddinTest_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Ribbon1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ThisAddIn.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml">
      <DependentUpon>ThisAddIn.cs</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ThisAddIn.Designer.xml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Ribbon1.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite">
      <Version>3.1.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools">
      <Version>3.1.4</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>WordAddinTest_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>002EE54C6C297029AF8A7691A5DAC8F51DACA96A</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Include the build rules for a C# project. -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- Include additional build rules for an Office application add-in. -->
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <!-- This section defines VSTO properties that describe the host-changeable project properties. -->
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/x" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
        <Host Name="Word" GeneratedCodeNamespace="WordAddinTest" IconIndex="0">
          <HostItem Name="ThisAddIn" Code="ThisAddIn.cs" CanonicalName="AddIn" CanActivate="false" IconIndex="1" Blueprint="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml" GeneratedCode="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs" />
        </Host>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: I think the version of office must of changed so the connection string is referencing the version of office.

Comment: @ RobertHarvey I've never used composition. Could you please suggest how to use it in my case? And I'll try that

Comment: @jdweng I'm using `Office365`. Another issue could be that the VSTO project being targeted for .NET 4.0 (it seems this is the minimum for VSTO4), while also referencing an assembly built for .NET 4.8. I'm not sure if you would have a suggestion/idea. If so, please let me know.

Comment: why do you need to use .net core libs?

Comment: The ACE driver is ACEOLEDB.DLL and is in a folder like : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15.  The dll is registered and if version of Net changes you may have issues.  Version 16 is Office 365.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev In your question, I assume you meant `EF-Core` (and not .net core). I'm trying `EF Core` because `EF-6` (none-core) has similar issue with `VSTO`  as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62121403/1232087). If you have any other suggestion for using `SQLite` in a `VSTO` project, I can try that.